# Derivatives of Polar curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, partial-derivative

So whats the derivative of r=1+2sin(θ)

Comment: I'm away from my computer so typing a full answer isn't feasible now. See this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarTangents.aspx

Answer (score 4):

$$x=r\cos\theta=\cos\theta+\sin2\theta$$ and $$y=r\sin\theta=\sin\theta+1-\cos2\theta.$$

Thus, $\dfrac{y^\prime_{\theta}}{x^\prime_{\theta}}=\dfrac{\cos\theta+2\sin2\theta}{-\sin\theta+2\cos2\theta},$ which for $\theta=0$ gives $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If x=r cosθ, then for r=1+2 sinθ wouldn't we get cosθ+2sinθcosθ ??

Comment: @John $2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin2\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

*(As a complementary note to the answer of @Michael Rozenberg)*

OP I think you did it in the following way:

> Differentiate both sides with respect to $\theta$, we have
>   $$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=2\cos\theta$$ When $\theta=0$, slope is $2$.

which is incorrect as $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ represents the change of radius against change of the angle.

Instead, we have to convert the polar equation into the Cartesian form to find the slope, i.e., the ratio of change of $y$-component against $x$-component.